# Omit files in a certain directory

Tags: dired, dired-omit-mode

I'm trying to omit html files from a certain directory when using dired.

For all directories I could do it like so;

```
(setq dired-omit-files "\\.html$")
```

I only want to hide html files from my org directory

Here is what didn't work

```
(setq dired-omit-files "\\/home/map7/org/\\.html$")
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `.dir-locals.el` file in the directory of interest, with the following contents:

```el
((dired-mode . ((dired-omit-files . "\\.html\\'"))))
```

If you want to omit the usual suspects as well, then use this regexp (which is the OR of the standard value with the `html` value above):

```el
"\\`[.]?#\\|\\`[.][.]?\\'\\|\\.html\\'"
```

Visiting the directory will ask about allowing the local variable which you can accept and enable for future visits with `!`. Assuming that one way or another, you have enabled `dired-omit-mode` (e.g. with `M-x dired-omit-mode RET`), then any `.html` files are omitted.

To enable `dired-omit-mode` always, see the doc string for the function: `C-h f dired-omit-mode`, which says:

> To enable omitting in every Dired buffer, you can put this in
> your init file:
>
> (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (dired-omit-mode)))

This applies to the directory of interest *and its subdirectories*. I don't know of a way to limit it to just the directory of interest using `.dir-locals.el`. It might be possible to do it using the more advanced mechanisms that are mentioned in the "Per-directory local variables" section of the manual (which you can get to with `C-h i g (emacs)directory variables RET`), but I have not gone down that route at all.

Comment: I am having trouble omitting `__pycache__` directory from `dired`. Could someone help with the correct regex? I used `re-builder` but it is not working.

Comment: You might want to ask a separate question but `"__pycache__\\'"` matches anything that ends with `__pycache__`. If you want to match it *exactly*, say ``"\\`__pycache__\\'"`` and if you want other cases, you can OR it using `\\|`  as above. Do `C-h i g (emacs) regexps` for more info.